# Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, hashset

I have an set where I put an int value into an set if it is still in in the set and create a string with an message for this case. If this id is not in the set, i put in the set and create a string with the specific message for this case.

Now I want edit this set into a 4 dimensional array or set.

Why I want this you can read in my code in the comment tags. I want to create an array or set with 4 values each, and then check if ID is in  there, if yes check if ID and "time value" is there and if both of these are in there check if ID, time, and number is in there,and so on and so on. For each case it should create a string with the specfific message Nr.  .... you can read it in my code.

Thank you very much !

```
   public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

             Text m;
             String w;
             String r = null;

              try {
                 m = new Text();
                 while(m.hasLine) {
                    w = m.nextline(); // Here I get the string which looks like :  First String: <name id="654" number=”345” value=”789” />   It is the first(Array should be empty, so I want String with Message:1 and fill Array with i2, i3 and i4
                                //After the first while loop ends I get then the second String : <name id="658" number="343" value="789" />   This ID is not in there, so I want the same as with first String. (Message:1 and set in Array i2. i3 and i4.
                                                                               //third String:   <name id="654" number="343" value="789" />   This ID is still in there, but 1 value (i3) is not in there, so I want Message: 3 and delete the existing content in the array with this ID, and create a new one with this i2,i3 and i4 value. In this case delete the array content from the first string above!
                                                                               //fourth String:  <name id="658" number="343" value="789" />    This is the same as in the second String, so create String with MEssage:2 and doesn't remove or add something in the array.

                                                                              // These 4 cases are all. CAn I do this with your code, sorry but i don#t really understand your code, can you help me to explain it or something like this. 

                    String z2 = w.substring(10,13);     // Here I get String : 654
                    String z3 = w.substring(23,26);     // String: 123
                    String z4 = w.substring(35,38);     // String: 345


                    Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(z2);   //Convert all to integer values
                    Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(z3);
                    Integer i4 = Integer.valueOf(z4);



                    TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new TreeSet<>(new CustCompare());
                       //CustCompare implemets the Comparator interface
                       ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

                       tmp.add(1);              //How I implement here my values in form of i2, i3 and i4 , do you know in every turn in my while loop I get a new line with the "new" i2,i3,i4  ; in the code a = m.nextline(); 
                       tmp.add(2);              // I don't understand How in this code I get these three integers into the array, or should I rename 1,2,3,4 in i2,i3,i4 ...???
                       tmp.add(3);
                       tmp.add(4);

                       a.add(tmp);

                       System.out.println(r);


                 }
              }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }
    }



class CustCompare implements Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>> {


    //String r = null;
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        String r;
        if (Objects.equal(a.get(0), b.get(0))) {
            if (!Objects.equal(a.get(1), b.get(1)) || !Objects.equal(a.get(2), b.get(2)) || !Objects.equal(a.get(3), b.get(3))) {
                b.set(1, a.get(1));
                b.set(2, a.get(2));
                b.set(3, a.get(3));
                r = "{\"Message\":3,";
                }
                return 0;
            } else {
                r = "{\"Message\":1,";
                return (a.get(0) - b.get(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help ?

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question, What I understood is, you want to create a set containing a set or 4-D array. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that' s it and I want to search in de set if value 1 of the 4 d array is still in there if yes ...check if value 2 and this value 1 is in there and if yes check if value 1,2 and three is in there . Overall I want to create a 4 d array and it should be possible to search for every 4 values. But if I have an 4 D array I can show it with an example!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** As we are using Set we can use the property of avoiding duplication by implementing our own "compare" method.
Use `Set<ArrayList<Integer>>` e.g.

```
...
TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new TreeSet<>(new CustCompare());
//CustCompare implemets the Comparator interface
ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

tmp.add(1);
tmp.add(2);
tmp.add(3);
tmp.add(4);

a.add(tmp);
...
```

Now implement the Comparator interface as follows(make minor changes as number of values in ArrayList)

```
class CustCompare implements Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        if (Objects.equals(a.get(0), b.get(0))) {
            if (!Objects.equals(a.get(1), b.get(1)) || !Objects.equals(a.get(2), b.get(2)) || !Objects.equals(a.get(3), b.get(3))) {
                b.set(1, a.get(1));
                b.set(2, a.get(2));
                b.set(3, a.get(3));
            }
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (a.get(0) - b.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

In above compare method if ID is same and values are different then they are replaced with new one. If all are identical then no change will be made.

Hope this is what you needed. Let me know if it works. I already checked the above code.

Comment: I have here a updatet code with my specific case, I think what you said is the right thing , but I have to check first if only the first Integer "i2" is in there. you can see it in my code in the comment tags.

Comment: are there more than one "i2" with same value?

Comment: i updated my code above, I think in my case I need a severall set where are only the "ID's" then check here first if it is in there.

Comment: Yes there are a lot more with the same i2 value you can see in the code that i get in every while loop a new line of a textfile, and when there came the same i2 value, then it should normaly differeent i3 and i4 values but it could be that there are the same , and in this case i need the string tih the specific message. it could also be, that there are i2 and i3 the same only i4 is not the same, in these cases i should delete these from the array and fill it new with these new i2,i3 and i4.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much, I think this is what I need, I changed my code above, can you still help me to set it in my code, I write it as comments in the code!! Thank You very much, but i need your help now!

Comment: Actually, I should not help you in that. But I will give you a hint. I assume that you also included the other `class CustCompare` in a code file. Add message lines in CustCompare's compare method. e.g msg 3 inside the 2nd  `if` and msg 1 inside outer `else`. Now, try yourself and let me know.

Comment: Ok, i edit my coide, you can see above, Now i get four times null, null,null, null, so for each line the result is null.

Comment: give me your all code file There are too many small errors also one sample text file. share a link for code file